# Exception on imageWithContentsOfFile - Acquire pthread write lock failed

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, asihttprequest

I am reproducibly getting an exception on this line

```
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path]; // Always main thread
```

The exception is not fatal, if breakpoints are disabled the app continues normally.  I presume the exception is caught in Apple's code.

The message logged is:

```
< Error >: ImageIO: CreateMetadataFromXMPBufferInternal  
Threw error #11 (Acquire pthread write lock failed)
```

Stack-trace:

[image: Stacktrace]

- The code is accessing a file path that the ASI Networking library owns.
- There is another background ASI thread thats checking for existence of the the URL string but I don't believe its actually writing anything to disk.
- The code is iterates over 8 successfully, then fails on the 9th.

Anyone seen this issue before or know whats causing it?

Comment: can you see if reading it off the main thread makes any difference?  e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961258/load-image-asynchronously-from-file

Comment: Yea good suggestion, ill give that a go for diagnosis purposes, but I don't really want to change the ASI as a solution.

Comment: I have this same problem.  Using `imageNamed:` does not give this error, but I don't want my images cached (for this instance).  I did a lot of testing and it came down to the specific image file.  Load a different image there and the error will not repeat.  I'm ignoring it now since I could not find a cause or resolution anywhere.

Comment: @Putz1103 - Interesting! Glad to know Im not the only one seeing this issue.

Comment: @Robert Same here.  I found pretty much nothing googling...